# WSO2 APIM Role validation

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 IS (5.10.0) as the key manager of APIM (3.2.0). I have published a graphql API which is secured by a scope (say 'test_scope' based on a role named 'test'). I have subscribed to the API with the Default Application and have generated the keys as well. When I generate the access token with the scope ('test_scope') and invoke the secured API I'm getting the valid response even though the required role ('test') is not assigned to the user. Below is the curl command which I'm using.

```
curl -k -X POST https://<IP>:8243/token -d "grant_type=password&username=Username&password=Password&scope=test_scope"
-H "Authorization: Basic Base64(consumer-key:consumer-secret)"
```

How to overcome this issue?

Comment: I experienced same situation, what i found so far is when i do same configuration on APIM 3.2.0 without IS - roles validation works as expected. I also described my situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66028479/problem-with-scope-results-during-token-generation-when-apim3-2-0-is-configured)

Comment: Could you see requested scopes in access token response ?

Comment: Yes. The requested scope is there in the token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have not enabled the **Scope Validator** for your application in the Service Provider settings in IS.

In IS management console;

- Go to the service providers list
- Go to the service provider for your application (eg: admin_DefaultApplication_SANDBOX) and select "edit"
- Go to "Inbound Authentication Configuration" > "OAuth/ OpenID Connect Configuration"  and select "edit"
- Enable "Role based scope validator"

[image]

Now only the users who have the relevant role to create the scope can access your APIs