# Problem with scope results during token generation when apim3.2.0 is configured with is5.10.0 as keymanager

Tags: oauth, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I found strange behavior during checking functionality of WSO2 AM + IS as key manager.

**Env I:**
WSO2 AM 3.2.0 (GA pack)

**Env II:**
WSO2 AM 3.2.0 (GA pack)
WSO2 IS 5.10.0 (GA pack)

**Configuration:**

created users: user-low, user-high
created roles: low, high
user-low has assigned low role
user-high has assigned high role
created shared scopes: high-scope, low-scope
high-scope pointed to high role
low-scope pointed to low role

published api with 2 endpoint

1. /unsecure (has pointed scope: low-scope)
2. /secured (has pointed scope: high-scope)

**Behaviour on ENV I (working fine - expected behaviour):**
After trying generate token by "user-high" with scopes high-scope, low-scope as a receive on endpoint: https://localhost:9443/generate-token
response:

```
{
   "accessToken":"eyJ4NXQiOiJNell4TW1Ga09HWXdNV0kwWldObU5EY3hOR1l3WW1NNFpUQTNNV0kyTkRBelpHUXpOR00wWkdSbE5qSmtPREZrWkRSaU9URmtNV0ZoTXpVMlpHVmxOZyIsImtpZCI6Ik16WXhNbUZrT0dZd01XSTBaV05tTkRjeE5HWXdZbU00WlRBM01XSTJOREF6WkdRek5HTTBaR1JsTmpKa09ERmtaRFJpT1RGa01XRmhNelUyWkdWbE5nX1JTMjU2IiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.eyJzdWIiOiJ1c2VyLWhpZ2hAY2FyYm9uLnN1cGVyIiwiYXV0IjoiQVBQTElDQVRJT04iLCJhdWQiOiIxeXZfaUZ2d3RvZmZ4RU90ZlJGZmpseGNjNG9hIiwibmJmIjoxNjEyMzU3NTExLCJhenAiOiIxeXZfaUZ2d3RvZmZ4RU90ZlJGZmpseGNjNG9hIiwic2NvcGUiOiJISUdIIGFtX2FwcGxpY2F0aW9uX3Njb3BlIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6XC9cL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo5NDQzXC9vYXV0aDJcL3Rva2VuIiwiZXhwIjoxNjEyMzYxMTExLCJpYXQiOjE2MTIzNTc1MTEsImp0aSI6ImQ3OTQ3ODc0LTRlNTMtNGI1My1iMWUwLTE0NGEwYTY2MDU5ZSJ9.KBol5clfIxScVPYVzdmBkz0APaE7uL8genldz8tx_G0FnaJStjn0tizDQfdcc46ZaEC1ahEfsGqBea6sJ8dpFucpf3ZqxnCz7CoJnVLU5F4lAXm_C3imWhOWLxF_wka0dlGExPDBpXQOmnspe2b45DSpIpz3zbTnnuClFM91tJkWrG9-k_ZIUHikI34m3aWltotXJzQJojdhL42pUCCttGcNGDbU9vfZ4wOcRx4fiVe6z0azvDBGP3FBSY00HyBFUo7ME9dqMaU_EDTybk77uLHyNGoQggOO42WU0ZfanrGlsYJSuzyQi4VVW3V1Uy6591b18LA28zq1c9Ay2-aMXw",
   "tokenScopes":[
      "HIGH",
      "am_application_scope"
   ],
   "validityTime":3600
}
```

**Behaviour on ENV II:**
After trying generate token by "user-high" with scopes high-scope, low-scope as a receive on endpoint: https://localhost:9443/generate-token
response:

```
{
  "accessToken":"eyJ4NXQiOiJNell4TW1Ga09HWXdNV0kwWldObU5EY3hOR1l3WW1NNFpUQTNNV0kyTkRBelpHUXpOR00wWkdSbE5qSmtPREZrWkRSaU9URmtNV0ZoTXpVMlpHVmxOZyIsImtpZCI6Ik16WXhNbUZrT0dZd01XSTBaV05tTkRjeE5HWXdZbU00WlRBM01XSTJOREF6WkdRek5HTTBaR1JsTmpKa09ERmtaRFJpT1RGa01XRmhNelUyWkdWbE5nX1JTMjU2IiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.eyJzdWIiOiJ1c2VyLWhpZ2hAY2FyYm9uLnN1cGVyIiwiYXV0IjoiQVBQTElDQVRJT04iLCJhdWQiOiJHU1RYeVdhNlNCeHRNRWhiVF91SnA4ZmtBNUlhIiwibmJmIjoxNjEyMzU3MDQ5LCJhenAiOiJHU1RYeVdhNlNCeHRNRWhiVF91SnA4ZmtBNUlhIiwic2NvcGUiOiJISUdIIExPVyIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOlwvXC9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6OTQ0M1wvb2F1dGgyXC90b2tlbiIsImV4cCI6MTYxMjM2MDY0OSwiaWF0IjoxNjEyMzU3MDQ5LCJqdGkiOiI0OTdhOTQ3OC0zZjg3LTQ0NmMtYjQ4OS1kMjI1MmQ2NDA2ZTYifQ.AoFKYLRsZBHELh8m0XBV0ndr19SMl0xMwzACG5-Q_ek7VRtWmocqJeAEjrXguUhcIUqHs843NPzcf185BpEjwCwJcXcR7ssIqxzINYSH0s7_LTm4X7XHMxV4cnF8gAiRnUQhGZQHgCyWI6NJ5VAcpIde5BnWaVcmx2Q5VFOFXGskfOB7325LcmhMS13Ni5oK2vb7YcTs059Zhoj13MrRnAOKoE1xrO9ioSVBXj9oX5RZ2uvdT_V3FQNWklc5jdMgebHDUQw-q_C5q9qhlGRZKql2ktcJ3OUeyGnJYEppuM0tOKCSTeH93MNcf6TAXYWEiRioa0FhRJblrfCIQrsHvA",
   "tokenScopes":[
      "HIGH",
      "LOW"
   ],
   "validityTime":3600
}
```

It's looks like in ENV II generating tokens not working properly. There is my questions:

1. Is it a bug of that versions or some misconfiguration issues?
2. If it's bug where i should start to try fix that situation, someone could point me where is implemented that functionality? (I want use opensource version over update products using WUM)
3. Is that situation was resolved in later versions of submodules, which are used to build product-api, and product-is?

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions!

Comment: This seems like an abnormal behaviour. Could you please open an issue in https://github.com/wso2/product-apim

Comment: I created issue [here](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/9856)